# Left join on 1:M relation by maximum value in non joinable column

Tags: sql, postgresql, hql

I am solving this kind of problem on PostgreSQL database using SQL.

I have 2 tables, for simplicity assume they have only these columns and have 1:M relation.

Table A:

| Name | Type | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | long | primary key |
| state | string | string holding enum value (for simplicity assume values X,Y,Z |

Table B:

| Name | Type | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | long | primary key |
| a_id | long | foreign key to A table |
| max | long | column holding maximum of bid |
| user_id | long | user who bid this bid |

What I am expecting from result of SQL:

**Select all table A ids which are in state Z** and user_id of table B record which **is highest and user_id is equal to 1** (so if there are 3 records in table B with max column values (1,2,3), it select the row with max value 3)

**Business request to clarify the question more:**

Get me all A table row ids, that are in state Z and user with some variable ID (lets say 1 for simplicity) has the maximum value in all children in table B.

I´ve tried to make some LEFT JOIN ON a.id = b.a_id and I know there will be some AND and some inner select with MAX(). but I am not really sure how to perform select max() when I do not maxing the joining column.

Comment: If you filter by `user_id` and `state` you only need to order by `max` and `limit 1`.

Comment: Well yea but It wont work with multiple ids will it? I need to get list of table A records that are in some state and given user has maximum bid (value in table B column) for that record.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
table_a a1 JOIN table_b b1 ON (a1.id=b1.a_id) WHERE (a_id,max) in
(SELECT a_id,max(max) FROM
table_a a JOIN table_b b ON (a.id=b.a_id) GROUP BY b.a_id) and b1.user_id=1;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Where is that filter clause for getting only records for user with given id? (user_id column in B table)

Comment: Basically what I understood, For particular id in table a there are multiple rows within table b and out of those multiple rows, we need row with maximum max value. Above query will show for all the id in table A

Comment: I editted above query to get rows with user_id=1 (example) you can modify/remove as per your requirement

Comment: Works like charm, thank you for your reply.